# showing messages from message board using firebase in react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i am new to firebase and I am following a tutorial from youtube on how to display messages realtime using firebase. I am not getting any error and I am unable to retrieve the messages from the cloud firestore. can someone kindly point me in the right direction, as I have tried everything i can but nothing seems to work. Below is a screenshot of my firestore database, and my code which has been trimed down to avoid any complexity.

[image]

```
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              message: '',
              messages: [],
            };
          }

          componentDidMount() {
            firebase
              .database()
              .ref()
              .child('/message-board/gFmLa20cKCzXilXSDGGq')
              .once('value', snapshot => {
                const data = snapshot.val();
                if (data) {
                  const initMessages = [];
                  Object
                    .keys(data)
                    .forEach(message => initMessages.push(data[message]));
                  this.setState({
                    messages: initMessages
                  });
                }
              });

            firebase
              .database()
              .ref()
              .child('/message-board/gFmLa20cKCzXilXSDGGq')
              .on('child_added', snapshot => {
                const data = snapshot.val();
                if (data) {
                  this.setState(prevState => ({
                    messages: [data, ...prevState.messages]
                  }));
                }
              });
          }


          renderItem({ item }) {
            return (
              <View style={styles.listItemContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.listItem}>{item}</Text>
              </View>
            );
          }

          render() {
            const { message, messages } = this.state;
            let emptyComponent = null;

            emptyComponent = (
              <View style={styles.emptyComponent}>
                <Text>No Messages Found</Text>
              </View>
            );

            return (
                  <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                    <FlatList
                      data={messages}
                      renderItem={this.renderItem}
                      ListEmptyComponent={emptyComponent}
                    />
                </View>
              </SafeAreaView>
            );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're using firebase code to retrieve data stored using Firestore. While they're both databases offered by firebase, they're different in their structure and how you access the information.

To get the messages one time might look like this:

```
db.collection("message-board").doc("gFmLa20cKCzXilXSDGGq")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Taken from these docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection

Since you're looking for realtime updates, that might look something like:

```
db.collection("message-board").doc("gFmLa20cKCzXilXSDGGq")
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
    });
```

Taken from: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen